# Calculating conditional probability

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, gibbs, conjugate-prior

Let's consider I have the pair of distributions: 
\begin{align}
X|t &\sim Binomial(n,t)  \\
t &\sim Beta(a,b)$
\end{align}
Here $n,a,b$ are known.

I need to construct conditional probability to sample from it, $t|X$. In this example I can do this analytically:

$$t|X \sim Beta(x+a,n-x+b)$$

But how can I do this in general case, for any distributions, either numerically or somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will do it the way you did in this case: you will compute the posterior using Bayes's Theorem. Unfortunately, in general, it won't be the case that the posterior has a nice identifiable simple form (your example is the nicest possible: the case of a [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)). In general, you will have to use some Monte Carlo solution. The [Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) algorithm allows you to explore any posterior, in principle, but there are limitations: simple versions of the algorithm, such as Random Walk Metropolis, may not perform well if you have a multivariate posterior which exhibits extremely high correlations between its components. When you can sample from the full conditionals, Giggs Sampling (which can be seen as a particular case of Metropolis-Hastings) is probably the way to go. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) for more information. Also, it may be the case that your problem needs an approximation technique such as [ABC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation), which is a hot topic nowadays.